# Hyperlink url for an asp.net gridview column

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have a gridview that returns values from a directory path such as :

```
            <table width="40%" border="0" style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">
                        <asp:GridView ID="gvFileList" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowSorting="true">
                            <columns>
                              <asp:boundfield datafield="Name" headertext="File Name"/>
                              <asp:boundfield datafield="Extension" headertext="File Type"/>
                              <asp:boundfield datafield="Length" headertext="Length"/>
                              <asp:boundfield datafield="LastCreateTime" headertext="Date"/>
                            </columns>
                        </asp:GridView>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

How can I get the values under the "Name" column to have a url similar to `"javascript:OpenSecure('abcd.doc')` ?

**Update:**
Given the HTML code below, I am unable to see the hyperlink in the Name field.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvInvoiceList" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowSorting="true">
                                <columns>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                                        <ItemTemplate><asp:Hyperlink ID="acctInvoiceRpt" NavigateUrl='<%# SetNavigateUrl(Eval("Name")) %>' runat="server"></asp:Hyperlink><%#Eval("Name")%></ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                  <asp:boundfield datafield="Extension" headertext="File Type"/>
```

Comment: Put displaying text before closing tag of Hyperlink. <ItemTemplate><asp:Hyperlink ID="acctInvoiceRpt" NavigateUrl='<%# SetNavigateUrl(Eval("Name")) %>' runat="server"><%#Eval("Name")%></asp:Hyperlink></ItemTemplate>, or use Text property...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert Name field to `<ItemTemplate>` and try adding a hyperlink

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hplName" runat="server"  NavigateUrl='<%# "javascript:OpenSecure(''' + Eval("Name") ''') %>' Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'/>
```

Comment: see my updated code. I am unable to see a hyperlink in the Name field;

Answer (score 1):

You would need a custom column for that:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228046.aspx